# Редирект в приложение Android/IOS

Tags: javascript, android, instagram

У меня есть сайт. На нем необходимо сделать редирект в приложение Instagram.
При нажатии на ссылку вида 
`<a id="testid" href='instagram://user?username=user_name'>тест</a>`
все работает. Но не работает редирект вида
`setTimeout(function(){window.location.replace('instagram://user?username=user_name' );}, 10);`

Comment: С JS слабо знаком, но `window.location.replace()`, мне думается, заменяет страницу в текущем окне. Вам же нужно открыть вообще другое приложение. Попробуйте `window.open()`

Comment: Почему вам надо использовать `setTimeout`?